# Cannot access Class Method from Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am setting up a very simple C# windows form application, it has a couple of forms that you navigate with buttons too. I am trying to add a class to control data access, but I cannot access the class from any of the forms. They are all in the same name space.
This is the form trying to access the class DataAccessLayer.LookupCombo

```
namespace LoanSaleControlPanel
{
    public partial class EditParticipant : Form
    {
        public EditParticipant()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void EditParticipant_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet Actions = new DataSet();
            Actions = LookupCombo("LST_Participant");
        }
    }
```

This is the class declaration

```
namespace LoanSaleControlPanel {
    class DataAccessLayer
    {
        public DataSet LookupCombo(string lookuptype) 
        {
            //Execute Queries and save results into variables
            DataSet Data = new DataSet();
            return Data;
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Being in the same namespace isn't enough. You need to access the method through a class object. `DataSet Actions = new DataAccessLayer().LookupCombo("LST_Participant");` Also notice there's no reason to create a new `DatSet` object that you're just going to throw away with the method call.

Comment: "Actions" is only scoped in the Load method.  If you want it available to the rest of the form, you would have to declare it at the form level.  The code you posted shouldn't be compiling, so you should be telling us the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. Either you declare the `LookupCombo` function as static, or you have to create an instance of `DataAccessLayer` and then access the function through that object.

Option 1:

```
public static DataSet LookupCombo(string lookuptype) { (...) }
```

Option 2:

```
DataAccessLayer layer = new DataAccessLayer();
layer.LookupCombo(myString);
```

Edit:

Regarding the option 1, I forgot to mention that you would have to call that function like this:

```
DataAccessLayer.LookupCombo(mystring);
```

Comment: Couldn't get option 1 to work, but option 2 is looking promising. Let me test a little more then come back thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is not static, so it would need either changing to static

```
public static class DataAccessLayer { ... }
```

And your method LookupCombo changing to static too... or you need to create a new instance of your class to access it.

I am pretty sure you are after the former so just add static to your class

Then you can access it with

```
DataAccessLayer.LookupCombo()
```